# CloudFlare Protect AJAX calls with Captcha/challenge

Tags: ajax, cloudflare

I have a headless JS application on domain `website.com`.
The website uses its own api, located at `api.website.com`.  The whole domain `website.com` is proxied via CloudFlare.

While under DDoS attack, I'd like to protect the website and API with captcha/challenge. I created a CloudFlare rule, that enforces captcha/challenge verification when hostname equals `website.com` or `api.website.com`.

When `website.com` challenge is passed, the actual website renders and the app makes ajax requests to API (`api.webiste.com`). The ajax request gets blocked by CloudFlare and required a separate challenge.

How to use `website.com` successful captcha verification and pass it to ajax api call under the same top level domain? Should I copy a cookie header and pass it to api call?